# Boolean always convert to zero in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, boolean-operations

I'm using Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Target SDK 31, Min SDK 23

I'm importing data from a web service that looks like this:
I added the last seven boolean values. The oncall was there before and have always worked, but the seven I added always return 0.

> "accountnum":"9922264","oncall":true,"oncalldate":null,"routepausefrom":null,"routepauseto":null,"mon":true,"tue":true,"wen":null,"thu":null,"fri":null,"sat":null,"sun":null

Then I add to the sqlite database;

> cusdatasource.createCustomer(Integer.parseInt(customerResult.d.results.get(i).accountnumStr),(customerResult.d.results.get(i).oncallBool) ? 1:0, OnCallDate,
> FromDate, ToDate,(customerResult.d.results.get(i).monBool) ?
> 1:0,(customerResult.d.results.get(i).tueBool) ? 1:0,
> (customerResult.d.results.get(i).wenBool) ?
> 1:0,(customerResult.d.results.get(i).thuBool) ?
> 1:0,(customerResult.d.results.get(i).friBool) ? 1:0,
> (customerResult.d.results.get(i).satBool) ?
> 1:0,(customerResult.d.results.get(i).sunBool) ? 1:0);

Here is the variables populated before added to the database.

> OnCall = 1
> OnCallDate = " "
> cusurl = ""
> vacfrom = " "
> vacto = " "
> Monday = 0
> Tuesday = 0
> Wednesday = 0
> Thursday = 0
> Friday = 0
> Saturday = 0
> Sunday = 0

All but the first onCall convert right, to either 1 or 0 depending if it is true or false, but all the other boolean always convert to 0 regardless.
I spend hours looking for something, but all the settings of all variables are the same for the working one and the not working one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to check for value separately ..  `(customerResult.d.results.get(i).oncallBool) ? 1:0` in this case if `oncallBool` is null you turn it to 0 but if its not null you always turn it to 1. You also have to consider the value , cause the value can also be true or false.

Comment: onCallBool is the only one that converts right all the time. If it's null it is 0, if it is false it is 0 and if it is true it is 1. None of the other ones convert to 1 when it is true they are always 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the Customer Class with the SerializedName is case sensitive and therefore even the result from the webservice was correct, the SerializedName didn't find the name, because I had Mon instead of mon.